# Command Line call from PHP not executed

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I'd like to start a python application from a php script which runs on a webserver. 
So far, so good. I tried

```
passthru("python track.py");
```

but it didn't work. Simply nothing happend. I tried exec() and system() as well just to make sure. 
Then I tried to run a php script with:

```
passthru("php test.php");
passthru("/usr/bin/php test.php")
```

Still nothing happening. But a

```
passthru("ls")
```

just works fine as expected.

I set the permissions that every user can edit and run the files.

Comment: `passthru("/path/to/python /some/path/to/track.py");`

Comment: Isn't working either :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a situation where the webserver user cannot read the file in question.

Unfortunately, `passthru()` simply returns `NULL` if a command fails, instead of throwing an exception. For example, even such nonsense as `var_dump(passthru('foobar'));` returns `NULL`.

How can you solve this? You can test from the command line if the webserver would be able to execute the command (assuming `www-data` is your webserver user, and you have sudo privileges):

```
sudo su - www-data -c 'python track.py'
```

This way, you'll get a meaningful error message and can solve the problem.

Comment: The webserver user is daemon (simply installed xampp to get up and running). When I execute the command you gave me I get the error `This account is currently not available.`. After that I shut down xampp as I thought it might block but the same error came again and again.

Comment: This usually means that the daemon user doesn't have a real shell, but instead something like `/bin/false` or `/usr/sbin/nologin`. You can check with `grep ^daemon /etc/passwd` (last column). To set a different shell like bash, run `sudo usermod -s /bin/bash daemon` and try the above stuff again. (Note: From a security standpoint, it makes sense to disallow interactive shells for daemon users, but if you want to use `passthru`, you have to do it.) Btw, you don't need to shutdown XAMPP for that.

Comment: Thank you. Now it starts up the python script but I got a strange error. `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/utils/path.py:304: UserWarning: IPython parent '/usr/sbin' is not a writable location, using a temp directory.
` I'm not sure if I should open up a new thread because it looks like a permission problem. Maybe you can help me with that as well :)

Comment: Yes, that looks like a permission problem. The script should probably actively set a working directory (which should not be the directory from which the script was started). In any case, this should be a different question.